# Should tabbing focus on datagridview

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, winforms

Should pressing the tab button within a windows form take the focus through a datagridview? What is the typical expectation of windows forms users from other applications?

The purpose of the form is to allow a non-technical user to construct a mapping between systems since information is represented differently on both sides.

I have included a portion of the UI below in case that helps add more context.

[image: portion of the mapping UI]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, defiantly! Tab should move to the next column, and if we're out of columns, the tab key stroke move to the next row. Also remember to save information while moving to the next cell. It is expected.

Comment: +1 but not sure about tabbing in the grid. W/Could be better to use arrow keys for that. Edit mode in a cell would of course reclaim arrow keys to navigate the text in the cell. Would be restored when leaving edit mode by enter (stay in that cell) or tab (move to next).